# How can I change the height of the keyboard in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, iphone-softkeyboard

I am working on Xamarin iOS. When the user clicks in a text box, the keyboard opens, but it's looking too big. I want to reduce the height of the keyboard and its keys. I attached two images.

Currently, the keyboard is looking like this:

[image: taller keyboard]

But I want the following keyboard type:

[image: shorter keyboard]

Comment: As the4kman said, it is not available to change the keyboard's height provided by system unless you customize the keyboard yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the keyboard's height manually in iOS is **not possible**.

The first image you linked is from a **4.7 inch** phone (e.g. iPhone 7), while the second is from an **5.5 inch** phone (e.g. iPhone 7 Plus).

The format of the keyboard depends on the device you are using.